# AngularJS: Count Filtered Items

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am showing subsets of a list if a checkbox is checked. I would like to replace the X next to the checkbox with the count of the list matching the selection criteria. I have a plunker that does everything but count the subset [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/caPb3sDQNcTH4M1h2IJx?p=preview).

My Controller looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope){
  $scope.cbMarvel = true;
  $scope.cbDCComics = true;

  $scope.heroes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Iron Man',
      fname: 'Tony',
      lname: 'Stark',
      location: 'Stark Tower',
      comic: 'Marvel'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Batman',
      fname: 'Bruce',
      lname: 'Wayne',
      location: 'Bat Cave',
      comic: 'DC'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Superman',
      fname: 'Clark',
      lname: 'Kent',
      location: 'Metroplis',
      comic: 'DC'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Daredevil',
      fname: 'Jack',
      lname: 'Murdock',
      location: 'Court Room',
      comic: 'Marvel'
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Flash',
      fname: 'Barry',
      lname: 'Allen',
      location: 'Speedline',
      comic: 'DC'
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: 'Hulk',
      fname: 'Bruce',
      lname: 'Banner',
      location: 'Labratory',
      comic: 'Marvel'
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      name: 'Hawkeye',
      fname: 'Clint',
      lname: 'Barton',
      location: 'Nest',
      comic: 'Marvel'
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: 'Thor',
      fname: 'Donald',
      lname: 'Blake',
      location: 'Asgard',
      comic: 'Marvel'
    }
  ];
});
```

And my view looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.2.0" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.0.3 current" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.20" data-semver="1.2.20" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.11.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
     <fieldset>
        <legend>Comments Log</legend>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="cbMarvel"/> Marvel [X]
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="cbDCComics"/> DC Comics [X]
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>

        <div class="row col-md-10">
            <div ng-if="heroes.length == 0"><b>No Heroes Found!</b>
            </div>
            <div ng-repeat="h in heroes | filter:{comic:'Marvel'}" ng-show="cbMarvel">
                {{ h.name}} - {{h.comic}}
            </div>
            <div ng-repeat="h in heroes | filter:{comic:'DC'}" ng-show="cbDCComics">
              {{ h.name}} - {{h.comic}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Daredevil is *Matt* Murdock, not *Jack*. Jack is Daredevil's dead father. (Oh Lord, I'm such a geek. I need professional help.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could set that count in the view model itself while binding the data or just have a method on the scope that returns the count.

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, filterFilter){
   ....
    $scope.getCount = function(strCat){
      return filterFilter( $scope.heroes, {comic:strCat}).length;
    }
    ...
});
```

and use it as:-

```
  Marvel [{{getCount("Marvel")}}]
  .....
  DC Comics [{{getCount("DC")}}]
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8YbRTd?p=preview)**

If the list is non changing when you are on the page i would suggest finding out the length and binding it to a property in the view model itself, and use it in the view.

```
 //Set your data model
  $scope.cbMarvel = {value:true, count:getCount('Marvel')};
  $scope.cbDCComics = {value:true, count:getCount('DC')};
```

and in your view

```
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="cbMarvel.value"/> Marvel [{{cbMarvel.count}}]
```

**[Plnkr2](http://plnkr.co/edit/lXTQMo?p=preview)**

If your dataset is huge, instead of using filter inside the getCount, use a forEach and populate the count for each type at once.

---

Infact you do not need a filter at all, it seems inefficient to iterate through the same list using a filter in your case. Your's is a static list so categorize it in the controller itself.

```
var comics = $scope.comics  = {}; //Dictionary of comics
  //Create the collection here.
  angular.forEach(heroes, function(itm){
    if(!comics[itm.comic]){
     comics[itm.comic] = {name:itm.comic, value:true, count:1, items:[itm] };
     return;
    }

    comics[itm.comic].count++; //Incr count
    comics[itm.comic].items.push(itm); //push specific item
  });
```

and remove all the filters in your view and do:-

```
    <div ng-repeat="h in comics.Marvel.items" ng-show="comics.Marvel.value">
        {{ h.name}} - {{h.comic}}
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="h in comics.DC.items" ng-show="comics.DC.value">
      {{ h.name}} - {{h.comic}}
    </div>
```

**[Plnk3 - the better one](http://plnkr.co/edit/5yFaB4?p=preview)**

Answer (score 28):

Assuming your list of people is in data variable and you filter people using query model, the following code will work for you:

- Number of visible people: `{{(data|filter:query).length}}`
- Total number of people: `{{data.length}}`

---

**summary**

`{{data.length}}` - prints total number of people

`{{(data|filter:query).length}}` - prints filtered number of people

Comment: i am very glad that my solution worked for you guys , thanks for ur support

Answer (score 15):

### Possible solution 1: Inline

You could actually save a reference to the filtered results in a variable: `h in filtered.marvel = (heroes | filter:{comic:'Marvel'})`, which you could use like so: `filtered.marvel.length`.

See: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MFAKVaF2K9fJxpGo3J1t?p=preview)

### Possible solution 2: In the controller

You could also move this code to your controller:

`$scope.filteredHeroes.marvel = $filter('filter')($scope.heroes, {comic:'Marvel'});`

, which you could use by `ng-repeat="hero in filteredHeroes.marvel"`

and `{{filteredHeroes.marvel.length}}`

(Don't forget to add $filter as a controller dependency)

See: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/j0yuDDlwXSnMNpXHbY8Z?p=preview)

Comment: It is really bad and inefficient to do a filter when there is no need to to use a filter.

Comment: How to do if multiple filter fields with OR condition??

Answer (score 0):

To find the count objects, I use `<scope_obj>.length` in the `.html` template.

Here's my controller:

```
conciergeControllers.controller('GuestMsgPreviewCtrl', ['$scope', 'GuestMessages',
    function($scope, GuestMessages) {
    $scope.guests = GuestMessages.query();
}]);
```

And template (each *guest* object has a *messages* attribute that is an array object, so `.length` returns the number of nested `message` objects:

```
<ul ng-repeat="guest in guests">
  <li>[[ guest.messages.length ]]</li>
</ul>
```