# AngularJS - how count filtered objects of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, filter, counter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working an event page with many filters. User can filter out events by severity, description, and duration. Severity levels of events can be 'critical', 'warning', 'ok'. Can anyone show me how to count the number of **filtered** events with each severity?. I expect something like this

Number of Critical Events: 4

Number of Warning Event: 7

Number of Ok Event: 2

When the number of filtered events change, these numbers will change accordingly. Thank you very much.

**Json**

```
{
   'severity': 'Critical',
   'description': 'content1',
   'duration': 1
}
{
   'severity': 'Warning',
   'description': 'content2',
   'duration': 2
}
{
   'severity': 'ok',
   'description': 'content3'
   'duration': 3
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' ng-model='search.description'>
<input type='text' ng-model='search.severity'>
<input type='text' ng-model='search.duration'>

<div ng-repeat='eventData in eventsData | filter:search:strict>
   <div>eventData.severity</div>
   <div>eventData.description</div>
   <div>eventData.duration</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087509/angularjs-count-filtered-items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by **filtering** the **eventsData** array combined with the **search filter** then getting the **length**.

**E.g.**

```
{{(eventsData | filter:search:strict | filter:'Critical').length}}
{{(eventsData | filter:search:strict | filter:'Warning').length}}
{{(eventsData | filter:search:strict | filter:'ok').length}}
```

**Here's the [JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/4yu4z93k/4/).**

**Your HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="YourCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search.description" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="search.severity" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="search.duration" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <p>Number of Critical Events: {{(eventsData | filter:search:strict | filter:'Critical').length}}</p>
    <p>Number of Warning Events: {{(eventsData | filter:search:strict | filter:'Warning').length}}</p>
    <p>Number of Ok Events: {{(eventsData | filter:search:strict | filter:'ok').length}}</p>
    <br />

    <div ng-repeat="eventData in eventsData | filter:search:strict">
        <div> {{eventData.severity}} </div>
        <div> {{eventData.description}} </div>
        <div> {{eventData.duration}} </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Your JS**

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('YourCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.eventsData = [
            {
                'severity': 'Critical',
                'description': 'content1',
                'duration': 1
            }, {
                'severity': 'Warning',
                'description': 'content2',
                'duration': 2
            }, {
                'severity': 'ok',
                'description': 'content3',
                'duration': 3
            }, {
                'severity': 'Warning',
                'description': 'content2',
                'duration': 2
            }, {
                'severity': 'ok',
                'description': 'content3',
                'duration': 3
            }
        ];
    }]);
```

Hope it helps.