# Count iterations and show count only once after satisfying ng-if in ng-repeat AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a line of code:

```
<div ng-repeat="ticket in scope.tickets track by $index" ng-if="ticket.film_id == film.id"> {{$index}} Ticket(s)</div>
```

Currently this shows the index and repeats the div element but I want the count for each instead and I only want to show the last count for each ng-if so that it looks like this in the end:

```
4 Ticket(s)
2 Tickets(s)
3 Tickets(s)
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Do the data transformation up front in a controller or better a factory... Are you using lodash by chance?

Comment: Are you using the ng-repeat to count the elements that pass the if?
You can do it with a filter as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087509/angularjs-count-filtered-items?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Please, provide more info. Are you in a nested `ngRepeat`? Would be great if you could add the source also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what I got from your question is that you're trying to count the objects in the inner `ngRepeat`, so you can use the *native* [**`filter`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

You just have to attribute the result of the `filtered` items using the `as` expression, as below:

```
<div ng-repeat="ticket in tickets | filter: { film_id: film.id }: true as filtered track by $index">
```

Here's a *simple* **demo**:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.films = [];
    $scope.tickets = [  
       {  
          "film_id":"id 1",
          "name":"ticket 1"
       },
       {  
          "film_id":"id 1",
          "name":"ticket 2"
       },
       {  
          "film_id":"id 1",
          "name":"ticket 3"
       },
       {  
          "film_id":"id 1",
          "name":"ticket 4"
       },
       {  
          "film_id":"id 2",
          "name":"ticket 5"
       },
       {  
          "film_id":"id 2",
          "name":"ticket 6"
       },
       {  
          "film_id":"id 3",
          "name":"ticket 7"
       },
       {  
          "film_id":"id 3",
          "name":"ticket 8"
       },
       {  
          "film_id":"id 3",
          "name":"ticket 9"
       }
    ];
    
    // 4 Films with id = 1, 3 films with id = 3, 2 films with id = 2

    function loadFilms(max) {
      var i = 0;
      while(i++ < max) {
        $scope.films.push({
          "id": "id " + i,
          "name": "film " + i
        })
      }
    }

    loadFilms(10);
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="film in films track by $index">
    <span ng-bind="film.id"></span>
    <div ng-repeat="ticket in tickets | filter: { film_id: film.id }: true as filtered track by $index">
    </div>
    <!-- to show 0 tickets just remove the ng-if check below -->
    <span ng-if="filtered.length" ng-bind-template="{{filtered.length}} Ticket(s)"></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. Thank you.